# Getting rows from dynamic table using variables

Tags: jquery

I discovered that I can do this to grab rows of a dynamic table between 2 and 5:

```
var limitTable = $(table).find('tr:gt(2):lt(5)');
```

But I can't do this:

```
var temp1 = 2;
var temp2 = 5;

var limitTable = $(table).find('tr:gt(temp1):lt(temp2)');
```

In my situation, I can't hard code values in the "gt( )" and "lt( )". It will depend on an incremented variable. Not sure what to do. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/47e9c264/74/)

Comment: need to use string concatenation to create the final selector using your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake on your strategy to use `temp1` and `temp2`. Use this to build the condition dynamically (notice how I concatenate variables)

```
var limitTable = $(table).find('tr:gt(' + temp1 + '):lt(' + temp2 + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand string concatenation but if I have temp1 = 2, what's +temp1+? Not sure I understand.

Comment: @Matthew Moon: the concatenation will add the value of `temp1` (in your case `2`). The result will be `'tr:gt(2)` for `temp1=2`

Comment: I see. It's the first time I've seen the +var+ notation. Thanks.